# Restoring/Attaching Oracle DB files on a new machine

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-backups, database-restore

I have been given some oracle database files and I need to retrieve data from them. The files include .ctl, .ora, .dbf, and .log. How can I attach/restore the database on a new install of oracle?

Answer (score 0):

Try beginning here: [Recreate Oracle Databse from .dbf files after re-installation of Oracle Enterprise 11gR2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26081353/recreate-oracle-databse-from-dbf-files-after-re-installation-of-oracle-enterpri)
With these files you should create a new instance, not try to "attach" it to an existing database.